# How to transfer a Video file From device to device

Tags: android

I want to develop an App which is just like snap chat,to send video files to friend.Is there any third party API to do this.What are the possible ways?

Answer (score 0):

One way is using [Sockets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm). You could basicly send information how many bytes the file has and then transfer it to other Socket where you will read it. You should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555668/java-send-file-using-sockets) question.

Edit:
In this solution you don't need any third party, it is java api.

Comment: Please mention the name of third party API or server

Answer (score 0):

Socket is good for transferring files, but i think you cannot transfer large files. And your application will allow lots of unwanted/unauthorized video being transferred between users.

You need to learn about [XMPP protocol](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/) and [Open Fire Server](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/), which are widely used by applications like WhatsApp (not sure what they currently using).

This may help you i think...

Try: Here is the example link to transfer files usind asmack and openfire server http://harryjoy.me/2012/08/18/file-transfer-in-android-with-asmack-and-openfire/

Answer (score 0):

You can use sockets but you can also use the [PubNut](http://www.pubnub.com/) API if you want focus in your app and leave the networking to a third party.

I hope this help you.

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment since this doesn't provide a direct answer but just an alternative.

Comment: @EWit I do not have enough reputation to comment, I'm sorry.

Comment: no worries, this was meant as a pointer hence no down vote or flag :).